# How do I get the elsif for @correct_tries to work properly?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, if-statement, scripting

My first hangman game from scratch is almost done with the real basic stuff. I just need a counter for when a player gets it right to work correctly. I haven't figured out a good way to do it without deleting everything and starting over.
the @correct_tries counts correctly then in the elsif compare the numerical value to the number of elements in the given word that were answered correctly.

It'll keep counting when it should have stopped when @correct_tries was compared to the number when .inspect happens on the array. But it keeps counting.

```
class Hangman

Profanity = ['cobol','snit','crap','court']
Adjective = ['foul','repugnant','swift','fast'] 
Noun = ['king','queen','prince','princess']


    def self.start_game
      print "Welcome to Hangman V1 by Clueless! Please select which category of words do you want to use:   \n Profanity, Adjective, Noun "
      @selection = gets.chomp.downcase
      case 
      when @selection == 'profanity'
        puts 'You have selected profanity! '
        hangman_word_selection
     when @selection == 'adjective'
       puts 'You have selected Adjectives! '
        hangman_word_selection
    when @selection == 'noun'
      puts 'You have selected nouns! '   
          hangman_word_selection
     end 
     end

    def self.hangman_word_selection

     if @selection == 'profanity'
       hangman_word = Profanity.sample
       hangman_word_setup(hangman_word)
       #puts '_ ' * hangman_word.size
     elsif @selection == 'adjective'
       hangman_word = Adjective.sample
       hangman_word_setup(hangman_word)
     elsif
            @selection == 'noun'
       hangman_word = Noun.sample
       hangman_word_setup(hangman_word)

    end
end

  def self.hangman_word_setup(hangman_word)
  hangman_word_array = hangman_word.chars.to_a
   @hangman_end = false
   #while(@hangman_end == false)
    #puts "*" * 40
    #puts 
    #puts
    puts 'You have five tries to get the word correct. If you can guess the whole word do so but you only have one try. Or just guess letter by letter.'
    p hangman_word_array
    @total_tries = 0
    @correct_tries = 0
    game_check = true

    while game_check == true
    first_try = gets.chomp.downcase



   if(first_try == hangman_word_array[0] || first_try == hangman_word_array[1] || first_try == hangman_word_array[2] || first_try == hangman_word_array[3] || first_try == hangman_word_array[4])
     puts 'Check'
     @correct_tries += 1
     p @correct_tries
     #correct tries equal to the number of chars in the given word check it.
    puts 'You have gotten it correct!'
    elsif(first_try == hangman_word)
     puts 'You have completed the word! Congratulations you win!'
              hangman_win
              break
     elsif(first_try != hangman_word_array)
     puts  'Wrong.'
               @total_tries += 1
               p  @total_tries
           #puts "*" * 40
      elsif(@correct_tries == hangman_word_array.inspect)
              puts 'done.'
              break


    end
    end
     end



  def self.hangman_loss
    puts ' +---+-
               |   |
               |   0
               |   |\\
               |   /\\
              -+----------'

  puts 'You lose!'            
  end


  def self.hangman_win

    puts 'NEED HANGMAN VICTORY POSE HERE.'

  end 

start_game

end
```

Comment: Note: Constants should be declared in `ALL_CAPS` names. Also use `case` to break out behaviour when you're comparing the same variable vs. multiple values, as you do where with `@selection`.

Answer (score 0):

The `elsif` condition
`elsif(@correct_tries == hangman_word_array.inspect)` will never be true. `@correct_tries` is a numerical value and `hangman_word_array.inspect` will return the array of words for hangman in a string format (e.g. `hangman_word_array = ['a', 'b', 'c']` then `hangman_word_array.inspect` will be `"[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"`.

Comment: Used .size but I guess it works in a way but the @correct_tries just restarts itself and doesn't break the loop?